# Mobile version of Amazon's PurchaseURL?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I'm getting the PurchaseURL from the CartCreate operation but i dont know how to link to a mobile friendly purchase operation or confirm add to cart, i'ts liniking to a site that has a really small interface in cellphones and doesn't look like amazon on mobile devices, but a really old and broken website, as if "something went wrong".

Maybe i can show that website inside an iframe and alter the CSS or something?

Is there a way to fix this?